# Objective C - OS GB Grid Ref to Lat Lon

Tags: ios, objective-c, operating-system, gis

Does any one know of a way to convert from OSGB easting northing to a WGS84 Lat Lon?

I'm currently using the CBLocation library to convert from Lat Lon to OS but I now need to do this the other way round.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am told this document tells how

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/support/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf